# Laravel 5.4: Exclude a route with parameters from CSRF verification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, csrf-protection

As per [Laravel 5.4 Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris), you can exclude a route from CSRF verification by adding the route to `$except` property at `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. But for some reason, a route with parameters couldn't be excluded with exact route name unless excluded from main route itself.

Expected route to be excluded:

```
protected $except = [
    'main/{id}/sub/*'
];
```

Only works through:

```
protected $except = [
    'main/*'
];
```

How do you exclude a route with parameters from CSRF verification?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since under the hood this feature uses `request()->is()` method, maybe this will work for you:

```
protected $except = [
    'main/*/sub/*'
];
```